# C3.js tooltip order

Tags: charts, tooltip, c3.js

Is it possible to change the order of the tooltip in C3.js?

Normally, c3.js orders entries by value. I want to have the order in a prescribed way, independent on the value. Data 1, Data2, Data3...

Answer (score 3):

There's `tooltip.order` option, but it's only available on the dev version (not in the latest release 0.4.11). Here's some info: https://github.com/c3js/c3/pull/1813

You can also use [tooltip.contents](http://c3js.org/reference.html#tooltip-contents), which also lets you customize the output.